# How to get the geometry of a polyline to a specific precision?

Tags: qgis, python

In python, I use `point = geom.asPolyline()` but it looks like I am not getting any precision just whole numbers?  How can I get the geometry and a certain precision?

Comment: Are you sure that your data contains values after the comma?

Comment: The following is the result: (1.30284e+06,399443).  Yes there are more digits to follow.

Comment: I am having the sample pickle.  I seek the output style of asPolyline(), yet its limited in precision.  Confirmed via use of asWkt(), which shows many more decimal places.